# Seeking author/title of a sci fi novel about interstellar probes and climate change, pub date 2010s

Tags: story-identification, novel

Can you identify the author/title of a big sprawling sci-fi thriller in which an American astronaut recovers a small alien object in Earth’s orbit? The object turns out to be an interstellar probe, one of many. Another character, a man from China or Hong Kong, is salvaging more of these probes from undersea. There’s also a woman who was terribly injured but patched together with advanced technology. A conspiratorial group is hunting down people who are in possession of the probes. The story takes place in the near future, when sea levels are higher.

I think the novel was published in the 2010s. I do recall that the author is a scientist (I don’t think it’s David Brin.)

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://inverarity.livejournal.com/65944.html?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [*Existence*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13039884-existence) (2012) by David Brin.

> Gerald Livingston is an orbital garbage collector. For a hundred years,
> people have been abandoning things in space, and someone has to clean
> it up. But there’s something spinning a little bit higher than he
> expects, something that isn’t on the decades’ old orbital maps. An
> hour after he grabs it and brings it in, rumors fill Earth’s infomesh
> about an “alien artifact.” Thrown into the maelstrom of worldwide
> shared experience, the Artifact is a game-changer. A message in a
> bottle; an alien capsule that wants to communicate. The world reacts
> as humans always do: with fear and hope and selfishness and love and
> violence. And insatiable curiosity.
>
> [image]

Main character is a garbage collector in space? Check.
Female character who's injured and rebuilt using tech? Check.
Sea levels rising? Check.
Sub-plot with Chinese character? Check.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you. So much for being sure it wasn’t David Brin!

Comment: @Joiner - When someone says "*It's like x*" or "*I'm sure it's not Y*", that's **literally the first thing I check**.